# Merge buckets with same name ignoring case

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

There is a `level` **analyzed field** with values like `"INFO"`, `"WARN"`, `"ERROR"`...

Sometimes the values can be lowercased like `"info"`.

When I do a simple **terms** aggregation in **Kibana** 2 buckets are created: one for `"INFO"` and another for `"info"`.

I've specified the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag without any success.

Is it possible to get this behavior without touching the **tokenization** of this field at the **ElasticSearch** level?

Comment: Do you have logstash?

Comment: No we don't use **LogStash** for these logs, they are directly injected into ES with a **log4net appender** (github.com/jptoto/log4net.ElasticSearch).

Comment: Obviously cleaning them up before putting them into elasticsearch would be better.  Logstash is great for that, or maybe you can find some other way in your flow.

Comment: Indeed **Logstash** seems great and we should use it for another workflow but directly logging from applications was simpler in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I've found a way to do that:

1. Go to the Kibana **"Settings"** tab
2. Choose the **index pattern** to configure
3. Choose the field to configure e.g. `level`
4. In **"Format"** select `String`
5. In **"Transform"** select `Upper Case`
6. Confirm by clicking the `Update Field` button

Now when I build most visualizations `"INFO"` and `"info"` are considered the same and are merged.

But table views still continue to consider them as distinct even if they both appear as `"INFO"`!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through `scripting`. Though `scripting` is not recommended as it makes the query very slow, but if you want to get the result without touching `tokenization` you can use below query.

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "group_level_ignore_case" :{
    "terms"   : {
        "script" : "doc['level'].value.toLowerCase()"   
    }
    }

  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems a good solution but I get a strange error `Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [2]: [aggs]`. I guess the format is not the one expected by my setup (**ES 4.2** + **Kibana 4.4**).

Comment: How can you have ES 4.4 . Latest version of elastic search is ES 2.2.0 which has got released last week.

Comment: I mean **ES 2.2**, I'm not a time traveler :)

Comment: `Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [2]: [aggs].","line":1,"col":84}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"logs-2016.02.08","node":"bUcNiCoNRaeYjc479UftCw","reason":{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [2]: [aggs].","line":1,"col":84}}]}}`. Probably the *JSON Input* format has changed or the documents are not as expected.

Comment: Even a basic script fails: `"script" : "'foobar'"` so the issue seems to be in the input format...

Comment: Is scripting enabled in elasticsearh.yml

Comment: Yes it is enabled: `script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on`